# Symfony2 using feature on every page

Tags: symfony

I'm thinking what is the best way of using some feature on every page of the website with Symfony. By saying feature I mean it can be like search input field or lets say top 5 articles. Currently I know the only way of rendering controller in a Twig. Are there any other ways of doing that?

The website will have different pages with the main content which will be different on every page. But every page should have a small block with listed top 5 articles and every page should have the same search form.

Comment: You have to be clarify your question. There are a lot of ways to reuse a piece of code either using twig template or classes.

Comment: Embedding controllers is your best bet: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers.  Ideally you would do this in your layout template.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice for you will be using [SonataBlockBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/installation.html).